# Data type mismatch while fetching data from one table into another

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to get data from a table CustomerCase of database TD_EDD; into a table CustomerCase of database DsVelocity. The problem is whenever I try to get the data, error message is generated because in CustomerCase table of TD_EDD database, there are 3 columns: LOB, ReferralSource and CaseType of type varchar; while in CustomerCase table of DsVelocity database, the 3 matching columns are LOBID, ReferralSourceID and CaseTypeID and are of type int.

I've simply tried to execute this query:

```
   INSERT INTO [DsVelocity].[dbo].[CustomerCase]
       ([CustomerID]
       ,[Tier]
       ,[EscalationDate]
       ,[ReferralSourceID]
       ,[ICMSID]
       ,[LOBID]
       ,[TriggerRC]
       ,[TriggerAccount]
       ,[Project]
       ,[CaseTypeID]
       ,[DateDue]
       ,[SARFiledYes]
       ,[SARFiledNo]
       ,[TeamLead]
       ,[SARAmount]
       ,[InitialNotes]
       ,[WorkFlowStatus]
       ,[CaseDecision]
       ,[AccountsReviewed]
       ,[ActionDate]
       ,[SecondLvlReview]
       ,[CompanyType]
       ,[IfOther]
       ,[ClientType]
       ,[MergeFlag]
       ,[MergeCaseID]
       ,[AMLREP]
       ,[HighRiskYes]
       ,[HighRiskNo]
       ,[AutoCreated]
       ,[FileName]
       ,[SourceRefDate]
       ,[SourceRefID]
       ,[ETMAdd]
       ,[ETMRemove]
       ,[ETMDate]
       ,[Investigator]
       ,[InUseBy])
   SELECT [CustomerID]
       ,[Tier]
       ,[EscalationDate]
       ,[ReferralSource]
       ,[ICMSID]
       ,[LOB]
       ,[TriggerRC#]
       ,[TriggerAccount]
       ,[Project]
       ,[CaseType]
       ,[DateDue]
       ,[SARFiledYes]
       ,[SARFiledNo]
       ,[TeamLead]
       ,[SARAmount]
       ,[InitialNotes]
       ,[WorkFlowStatus]
       ,[CaseDecision]
       ,[AccountsReviewed]
       ,[ActionDate]
       ,[2ndLvlReview]
       ,[CompanyType]
       ,[IfOther]
       ,[ClientType]
       ,[MergeFlag]
       ,[MergeCaseID]
       ,[AMLREP]
       ,[HighRiskYes]
       ,[HighRiskNo]
       ,[AutoCreated]
       ,[FileName]
       ,[SourceRefDate]
       ,[SourceRefID]
       ,[ETMAdd]
       ,[ETMRemove]
       ,[ETMDate]
       ,[Investigator]
       ,[InUseBy]
   FROM [TD_EDD].[dbo].[CustomerCase]
```

and then ran into the following error:

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'CRR' to data type int.
```

CRR is a data in the column ReferralSource.

Similar messages may appear in case of LOB and CaseType columns

The database server I'm using is MSSQL Server 2008 R2.

What is the solution to this problem???

EDIT-1: Tried using Inner Join with LOB, CaseType and ReferralSource tables. Now the error has disappeared, query ran ok, but I get data from only 2 rows. I can't understand why?????? I had more than 40 data in the [TD_EDD].[dbo].[CustomerCase] table, so all these data were supposed to be passed to the [DsVelocity].[dbo].[CustomerCase] table. What's wrong?

EDIT-2: Got it. CaseType column in [TD_EDD].[dbo].[CustomerCase] had mostly NULL values, only 2 rows had valid data. Hence, only 2 rows were sent to [DsVelocity].[dbo].[CustomerCase] becasue no corresponding ID match can be made for null values. I guess I figured it out myself. Thanks everyone.

Comment: If data type really is different do a CONVERT within your select. Otherwise more info needed, a CREATE TABLE statement for both tables would be a great start

Comment: You could probably include in your post here the tables that you have in your database and the structure of each tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try casting as already suggested or probably you're referring the wrong field name, like (I shall focus only on the one that has an error):

```
SELECT 
   ,[ReferralSourceID]
   ,[LOBID]
   ,[CaseTypeID]
FROM [TD_EDD].[dbo].[CustomerCase]
```

Instead of `ReferralSource` use `ReferralSourceID`, instead of `LOB` use `LOBID` and instead of `CaseType` use `CaseTypeID`.

Or probably you need to reference the Reference Table on those fields like:

```
SELECT 
   ,[ReferralSourceID]
   ,[LOBID]
   ,[CaseTypeID]
FROM [TD_EDD].[dbo].[CustomerCase] CC
INNER JOIN Referral R
ON CC.ReferralSource = R.ReferralSource
INNER JOIN LobTbl L
ON CC.LOB = L.LOB
INNER JOIN CaseTypeTbl C
ON CC.CaseType = C.CaseType
```

Comment: @All, FYI, 1. I want to get all data from the TD_EDD database 2. There are 3 tables in both databases, named LOB, CaseType and ReferralSource. Each of these tables have columns -CaseTypeID, LOBID and ReferralSourceID, also have columns - LOBName, CaseTypeName, ReferralSourceName. In the TD_EDD Database, in CustomerCase table, the LOBID value stored is actually LOBName, same case in other two columns. I want to get the corresponding ID for these name values while passing them to DsVelocity database's CustomerCase table, which I'll get from their tables. Hope it's clear now what I want to do.

Comment: I just want to clarify coz I am not clear in your response. Do you have LOBID, ReferralSourceID and CaseTypeID in TD_EDD database and specifically in CustomerCase table? If yes then use it. If not, are you saying it is saved on other tables as Reference tables say for LOB there is LOBtbl, for ReferralSource there is ReferralSourceTbl? If there are references table then you have to do JOIN as i've posted above. Otherwise if my interpretation is wrong please identify all the tables on the TD_EDD database and what are these tables. If possible the fields also.

Comment: thanks. Yes, there are reference tables and yes, there are LOBID, ReferralSourceID and CaseTypeID in TD_EDD database in CustomerCase table. I used join as you suggested and now the problem is solved. Thank you once again for your patience and time.

Comment: @CrescentMoon: Glad that it worked for you. Happy coding and GOD bless.

Answer (score 0):

Try [casting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) your varchar columns to int (assuming the data in your source columns is valid for int columns in target)

```
SELECT CAST(ReferralSource AS int), 
CAST(LOB AS int),
CAST(CaseType AS int)
--etc
```

Comment: Note that this will only give sensible conversions if the three varchar fields containg string representations of integers; "SomethingElse" will not properly convert.